# I cannot update ruby on rails production code using SFTP(Filezilla software), by downloading file and edit on my local machine text editor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Ruby on Rails app in godaddy server, and I used Filezilla to connect on the server, I tried to edit one of the files from the views folder of my app, and downloaded it to edit on my local machine text editor(sublime text), then upload it again using Filezilla. When I tried to refresh the browser, there were no changes happened.

Any help guys?
Thank you in advance.

I already tried to update files using Putty via ssh, but still it doesn't affect my app on the production.

Comment: you have to restart rails server, or should deploy application with tool like capistrano

Comment: Thanks Thorin, I just don't know how to restart rails on production until I used Capistrano on my local development: "cap production deploy:restart", then I can now see my updates. Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the description mentioned in the post the below mentioned case must be considered:

When doing a remote ssh and doing changes on the server, you need to restart the server only if your application is running in production environment as changes are not autoloaded in this environment.

Suggestion:

As a mode automated approach than your current one, you should be using capistrano for deployment.

https://github.com/capistrano/rails

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, I used Capistrano "cap production deploy:restart" to restart the rails on production. I can now see my updates. :) Thanks